# Setting the column value based on the column value of complete df in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can some help me to solve the use case:
Below is the dataset

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|artistId   |musicalGroups|displayName |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|wa_16      |wa_31        |Exods       |
|wa_38      |wa_16        |Kirk        |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

I want to populate a column **name** based on the **musicalGroups** value and the set the **name** as per the **artistId** **displayName** columns value to it.
Like in the below example we have wa_16 as the artistId whose name is Exods, so **name** column should have displayName as per the artistID of it.
Example:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|artistId   |musicalGroups|displayName |name
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|wa_16      |wa_31        |Exods       |null
|wa_38      |wa_16        |Kirk        |Exods
+-----------+-------------+------------+

Tried via self join on artistId and musicalGroups, but it was not working.
Can some help me to solve this usecase?
```

Comment: pls check and let us know if the below code works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = `your existing dataframe`

// Derive new dataset from the original dataset
val newDF = df.select("artistId", "displayName").distinct()

// Join new dataset with original dataset based on the common key and select the relevant columns
val combinedDF = df.join(newDF, df.col("musicalGroups") === newDF.col("artistId"), "leftOuter").select(df.col("artistId") as "artistId", df.col("musicalGroups") as "musicalGroups", df.col("displayName") as "displayName", newDF.col("displayName") as "name")
```

Comment: This way it is setting a wrong value.
In this it is setting value as per the artistId but we need to search for the musicalGroup value in the complete df and then set the value to that row which is having the artistId name to it.

Comment: Through the above join you get the name for all the rows, based on the `musicalGroup` and it's relative `artistId` combination.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, You can use **`pivot()`** and **`groupBy()`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("wa_16","wa_31","Exods"),("wa_38","wa_16","Krik")],["artistId","musicalGroups","displayName"])
df_grp = df.groupBy("artistId", "musicalGroups", "displayName").pivot("displayName").agg(F.first(F.col("artistId")))
df.show()
df_grp.show()

+--------+-------------+-----------+
|artistId|musicalGroups|displayName|
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|   wa_16|        wa_31|      Exods|
|   wa_38|        wa_16|       Krik|
+--------+-------------+-----------+

+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+-----+
|artistId|musicalGroups|displayName|Exods| Krik|
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+-----+
|   wa_16|        wa_31|      Exods|wa_16| null|
|   wa_38|        wa_16|       Krik| null|wa_38|
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+-----+
```